# Pebble Watch pushing data to iOS when app is in background mode

Tags: ios, bluetooth, pebble-watch

I have been searching everywhere and struggling to find a clear answer. I would like to know if when in background mode, or when the phone is locked, a pebble watch app can communicate with the iPhone to send events.

An example of what I am using it for (in its most basic form) is a stopwatch that runs on your phone and watch. The user can start, stop etc from the pebble watch and the iPhone will send user events to a server...

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Watchface <-> Phone app documentation](http://developer.getpebble.com/1/02_Guides/07_CommunicatingPhone) clearly states that:

- Only one iOS application can be connected to the watch at a given time;
- Only the iOS application can (re-)open the channel to the watch app.

So your watchface app will be able to send messages to the app, as long as:

- Your iOS application is the last 3rd party app that used the channel to the watch
- Your iOS application was not killed in the background (for example, you declared a background mode to make sure you would stay online)

Finally, note that the SDK provides you with a callback when the message are not delivered so your watchface app would know if the app was killed and would be able to display a specific message to the user.

This is my understanding of the documentation but I have not been able to try that yet.

Comment: Thanks for that sarfata! Will let you know how development goes.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. The callback that handles failed messages from the watch to the phone is `.out_failed`  There's an example of it in `demos/feature_app_message_send` but the content of the actual callback in that example is a `TODO` comment.